# "Simplify your negation so that no quantifier lies within the scope of a negation." What does this mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

I'm getting an alert from the script that says my question appears to be subjective, but I don't think it is. What I seek is an explanation as to what the statement in the title in quotes means. It asked me to do this for a specific statement in predicate logic, but I couldn't find a way to type out some of the symbols, which i am researching on my own right now.

Any help is appreciated, as I have a test on material like this tomorrow morning.

Comment: For typing logic: put your formula inside dollar signs \$...\$ and use symbols \forall, \exists, \neg, \wedge, \vee to get $\forall, \exists, \neg, \wedge, \vee$.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried that, but I didn't know i needed the $$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, it means that you should simplify 
$$\neg \forall x[P(x)]$$
to the equivalent $$\exists x[\neg P(x)]$$
and to simplify
$$\neg \exists x[P(x)]$$
to $$\forall x[\neg P(x)].$$
A "quantifier in the scope of a negation" would be when the negated stated includes a quantifier and they can always be eliminated by the two above simplifications.